# auto invoice on email confirmation

Tags: php, magento, checkout, observers

I need to programmatically invoice orders in Magento on certain product types when an order has been successfully placed. This is for a virtual giftcard, and in order for the giftcard number to be emailed out the order has to be invoiced in the admin backend.

I think that there is functionality like this for "virtual goods" already, but my product has the type 'giftcard', not 'virtual' and I therefore had to do this myself.

So far I've managed to make sure that the product can only be ordered alone, so no physical products mixed in into the order. Also I have been able to detect the giftcard at checkout to hide any non-direct or non-assured payment methods.

Now all I had to do was to add an observer to check the order status change to "payment received (reserved on account)" or just "payment recieved" from any previous order statuses, like "payment pending".  It's just that there is no such event in Magento - at least as far as I can tell by searching.

So I figured that I'd connect the auto-invoice code to where Magento sends out the order confirmation email - but I simply can not find where that is.

Any suggestions on where I can insert my code to auto invoice the order?  Preferably as "safe" as possible in regards to payment received - but I'd settle with anything and can always go back manually and block giftcards connected to suspected frauds and orders where the payment is somehow not received.

Thanks in advance for any hints on how to accomplish this!

Comment: Since I don't already have auto invoice on for normal orders, I do not seem to be able to use: `sales_order_payment_capture` or `sales_order_payment_pay`. But I might be on to something. By using the event `sales_order_payment_place_end` I think that the order state gets set correctly to 'new' on orders that get the status "payment reserved/received" in my backend - as per this explaination: http://blog.baobaz.com/en/tag/magento-state-and-status

Comment: Trying with event `sales_order_place_after` now instead, to get the order object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best option is to observe event `sales_order_place_after`, `sales_order_payment_place_end`, which are fired when an order payment is placed ([see here](https://github.com/varinen/solvingmagento_1.7.0/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php#L1092)). 
To be 100% sure add a code to your observer to check that the order due is equal zero `$order->getTotalDue() == 0`

Comment: Thats what I'm trying now, but it seems to run before the order is really placed. If I run code to invoice the order inside that observer, the order seems to go directly from state 'processing' to state 'complete', not sure if I can be confident that the payment will go through.

Comment: From the shop's view this logic it is correct - a virtual good, such as a giftcard, does not need to be shipped, so as soon as an order is paid and invoiced its status changes to "complete". Do you want to avoid this status change because you can't be sure if the payment went through? Does your payment method provide any means to ensure that?

Comment: While the user is away paying with his credit card on a 3rd party website the order state is set to `processing`, so I'd need to wait for that to clear and the state changes to `new`. I could easily check the order state, but unless I can put my code in some observer after the credit card payment is done only thing I can do is print error and abort. Do you know of any event later in the process, like when the "order complete" email is sent, or at the cart/success page perhaps? One solution would be for me to override the core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php file's successAction

Comment: Well, the checkout success action does send an event you can use: `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` - by this time a confirmation email is sent and the order is placed. However, I think this will not ensure that some other payment methods are through. For example paypal can still be under review and eventually fail.

Comment: `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` did the trick! :D Thanks!